# Preciso de um gerador sequencial em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso de um código que eu coloque a URL e o numero de repetições no input e quando clicar para gerar a sequencia sair assim no textarea:

```
rede[0]="http://www.siteescolhidoaqui"; rede[1]="http://www.siteescolhidoaqui"; rede[2]="http://www.siteescolhidoaqui"; rede[3]="http://www.siteescolhidoaqui"; rede[4]="http://www.siteescolhidoaqui"; rede[5]="http://www.siteescolhidoaqui";
```

deste jeito acima começando no zero até o numero escolhido por mim e sempre o mesmo url escolhido...
javascript e um mini formulario em html para colocar a URL e o numero de repetições...
acredito que seja facil, alguem pode me ajudar?

tentei esse que o renan comentou e consegui:

```
<script>
(function() {

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', toTextarea);

  function toTextarea() {
    var $urlInput = document.querySelector('input[type="url"]'),
        url       = $urlInput.value,
        inputName = $urlInput.getAttribute('name'),
        repeat    = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]').value;

    if (url && repeat) {

      var output = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
        output += inputName + '[' + i + ']="' + url + '"; ';
      document.querySelector('textarea').textContent = output;
    }
  }
})();
</script>
<input placeholder='URL' type='url' name='rede'>
<input placeholder='Sequencia' type='number'>
<button>Ir</button>

<textarea placeholder='Resultado'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não ficou claro se você a sequência deve considerar o índice ou a quantidade de elementos. Por exemplo, 5 repetições baseando-se pela quantidade:

```
[0][1][2][3][4] = 5 elementos.
```

Ou, 5 repetições considerando o índice:

```
[0][1][2][3][4][5] = 6 elementos.
```

No caso de ser a segunda, basta alterar o loop abaixo para ir de 0 até que `i` seja `<=` o valor de repetições:

```js
(function() {

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', toTextarea);

  function toTextarea() {
    var $urlInput = document.querySelector('input[type="url"]'),
        url       = $urlInput.value,
        inputName = $urlInput.getAttribute('name'),
        repeat    = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]').value;

    if (url && repeat) {

      var output = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
        output += inputName + '[' + i + ']="' + url + '"; ';
      document.querySelector('textarea').textContent = output;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<input placeholder='URL' type='url' name='rede'>
<input placeholder='Sequência' type='number'>
<button>Ir</button>

<textarea placeholder='Resultado'></textarea>
```

Comment: É exatamente isso aparentemente, porém não está dando certo aqui, quando clico em ir não sai nada no resultado

Comment: Aqui onde? Testei no Firefox, Chrome, IE e Edge, em todos eles está funcionando.

Comment: Eu uso o Firefox e Opera vo te mandar um email vc ve se ta certo por favor